# Regular expression to extract software version from the given text?

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

I am looking for a regular expression that can extract the software version from a string. Few samples look like

```
1) 'ABCD 2.3.4' 
o/p: 2.3.4

2) 'ANDROID 4.4 KIT KAT SELFIX'
o/p: 4.4

3) '0.1.0-D-20170309.1502'
o/p: 0.1.0

4) 'CONTIXO-LA703-20180915-v1.0'
o/p: 1.0
```

My regex condition failing and unable to satisfy all these conditions.
Here is my regex:

```
''.join(re.findall("[0-9.]", txt))
```

This can only satisfy the first two cases. How can I extract the software version from all the above cases?

**Note**: My old question was not specific and was closed without a solution. I deleted the question and added a new one. Hope this one meets the standard.

Comment: In example 3, the version could be `0.1.0` or `20170309.1502`.  How do you know which one is the version number? (To a human, the second one is clearly a timestamp)

Comment: The length of the number would make the difference in this case

Comment: Maybe something like this would work `\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}(?:\.\d+)?\b` It works on your provided examples but it might not work on some cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***In Python3:*** Use following, in case there are multiple matches present get the first one.

```
import re
re.findall('\d+(?:\.\d+)+', '3) \'0.1.0-D-20170309.1502\'')[0]
'0.1.0'
re.findall('\d+(?:\.\d+)+', '2) \'ANDROID 4.4 KIT KAT SELFIX\'')[0]
'4.4'
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
\d+          ##Looking for digits 1 or more occurrences here.
(?:\.\d+)+   ##Starting a non-capturing group which looks for a literal DOT followed by one or more
             ##digits occurrences AND one or more occurrences of this non-capturing group with `+` it will match.
```

---

---

As per The fourth bird's nice comment, you could try following too:

```
(?<![\d-])\d+(?:\.\d+)+
```

Comment: Why is this marked as the answer when it gets a double match on example 3?

Comment: @RufusVS, It is fixed now, its providing expected results as per OP's shown samples, thank you.

Comment: @RufusVS I got the core logic and whatever the picking form the list is self-explanatory. So I marked and accepted the solution